# does the value of row_rowscn goes with the import?

Tags: oracle

I have a table that contains million of rows with rowdemendencies enabled , and I took dump for it. now I want to import the data of this table with specific year and rowdependcy value. if I import the table with only date condition ,it will return corrects values ,if I add the rowdempdency value it will return different wrong rows.

For example

```
Id ora_rowscn
1, 123456
2  123457
3  123458
4  123459
5  123450
```

`select * from tb1 where id >2`
it return 3 rows out of 5 , if add `and orw_rowscn <'123459'` it return nothing. As per my understanding this behavior normal. is it correct or I am doing something wrong ? and is there a way where I can get specific date and rowdependency values ?

the needed ouput is this

3  123458

Comment: `orw_rowscn` <> `rowdempendcy`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes i didnt undestand you , enabling rowdependcy will change the values of row_scn in every dml after commit.

Comment: What does `specific year and rowdependcy value` mean?  If you are trying to import the data without changing the `ora_rowscn` from the original database, that is not possible and would not make sense.  If `rowdependcy` is a column in the table then doing an import should not change the value in the column.  If it is changing, I'd look to see if there are triggers or something similar on the table.

Comment: @JustinCave ora_rowscn here is not column its is a psuedocolum becuase the rowdempendcies on the tables is enable. So my question is the pseudo column ora_rowscn value does it go with the dump file ? or it will be changed ? I dont care if it will be changed after the import in the database. all I am checking if i can read the value of ora_rowscn from the dump file. undersstand me ?

Comment: What I mean is that you show us a table with a column named `rowdempendcy` (which is probably a typo) but then test a column named `orw_rowscn` in the where clause. This is quite confusing.

Comment: The ora_rowscn is not preserved when you do an expdp/impdp. So don't count on it for your work. If you want such a thing, add an actual column to your table and have it populated by using userenv('commitscn') in your INSERT statement or any other mean, like selecting current_scn from v$database and using it.

Comment: @Baalback Can you edit your question to include the Oracle version and architecture? I verified that a PDB clone preserves the ORA_ROWSCN numbers - although even that cumbersome solution will only work if you have a multitenant architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORA_ROWSCN` appears to be preserved if you export the *tablespace* instead of just the table. Regular data pump exports and imports will always change the SCN anyway, so there's no reason why Oracle would save that extra information normally. But since transportable tablespaces copy the entire data file, that extra SCN information comes along with the file.

You'll likely want to create a separate tablespace just for this one table, so you don't need to copy over a lot of extra objects.

**DANGER**

This solution worked on my machine, and that's the only guarantee I can make. This is partially undocumented behavior, and it may not work on other versions, editions, or platforms. And then there's also the problem of `ORA_ROWSCN` values occasionally changing based on how the table is queried, even if the table does not change. `ORA_ROWSCN` is not designed to be used this way, but maybe if you're lucky it will work for you.

You'll want to carefully test this solution before applying it.

**Script**

My script is mostly based on [this helpful tutorial about transportable tablespaces from Oracle-Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/transportable-tablespaces). I changed the table to a simpler table to demonstrate that the `ORA_ROWSCN` stays the same, changed some connections and physical attributes to match my system, and I remapped the schema name and tablespace name to demonstrate how to copy the data to the same database but as a different schema.

The script is a bit of a mess, and you'll need to make some significant changes to make it fit your environment.

```
sqlplus /@orclpdb as sysdba

CREATE TABLESPACE test_data
  DATAFILE 'D:\19C\APP\JON\ORADATA\ORCL\ORCLPDB\test_data01.dbf'
  SIZE 1M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1M;

CREATE USER test_user IDENTIFIED BY test_user
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE test_data
  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
  QUOTA UNLIMITED ON test_data;

GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE TO test_user;

create table test_user.test1(a number) rowdependencies;

begin
    for i in 1 .. 10 loop
        insert into test_user.test1 values(i);
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/

select a, trim(to_char(ora_rowscn, '999999999999999')) from test_user.test1 order by a;

From original schema:
A   TRIM(TO_CHAR(ORA_ROWSCN,'999999999999999'))
1   39460713200691
2   39460713200694
3   39460713200697
4   39460713200699
5   39460713200702
6   39460713200704
7   39460713200706
8   39460713200708
9   39460713200710
10  39460713200712

begin
    SYS.DBMS_TTS.TRANSPORT_SET_CHECK(ts_list => 'TEST_DATA', incl_constraints => TRUE);
end;
/

SELECT * FROM sys.transport_set_violations;

ALTER TABLESPACE test_data READ ONLY;

--Modern versions always have this directory working.
-- On my PC: D:\19c\app\jon\admin\orcl\dpdump/9943A0901A94486A900B0716D7E1B70F
select * from dba_directories where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';

expdp userid=\"/@orclpdb as sysdba\" directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR transport_tablespaces=test_data dumpfile=test_data.dmp logfile=test_data_exp.log

-- Copy the datafile to the same location, but with a different name.
copy "D:\19C\APP\JON\ORADATA\ORCL\ORCLPDB\test_data01.dbf" "D:\19C\APP\JON\ORADATA\ORCL\ORCLPDB\test_data02.dbf"

ALTER TABLESPACE test_data READ WRITE;

-- TARGET DB (I'm using the same DB):
CREATE USER test_user2 IDENTIFIED BY test_user2;
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE TO test_user2;

impdp userid=\"/@orclpdb as sysdba\" directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=test_data.dmp logfile=test_data_imp.log remap_schema=test_user:test_user2 REMAP_TABLESPACE=test_data:test_data2 transport_datafiles='D:\19C\APP\JON\ORADATA\ORCL\ORCLPDB\test_data02.dbf'

select a, trim(to_char(ora_rowscn, '999999999999999')) from test_user2.test1 order by a;

From new schema - notice how the values are the same as above:
A   TRIM(TO_CHAR(ORA_ROWSCN,'999999999999999'))
1   39460713200691
2   39460713200694
3   39460713200697
4   39460713200699
5   39460713200702
6   39460713200704
7   39460713200706
8   39460713200708
9   39460713200710
10  39460713200712
```

Comment: thanks jon your answer was helpful and gave some things to think about it

Comment: the transportable prameter if its set to always while exporting a table using data pump might move the ora rowssnc values ? or only transotable works on tablespace ?

Comment: @Baalback I didn't know that parameter existed. Based on my understanding of the documentation, I think you must set `TRANSPORTABLE=ALWAYS` to preserve the ORA_ROWSCN values. Either way, the entire datafile needs to be copied over. In the worst case, if transportable table mode doesn't work, you could write a post-import script to drop everything attached to the tablespace except for the one table you care about.